# Можно ли делать таблицы без PK и как быть с индексами?

Tags: mysql, sql

Мне надо на страницу вывести огромную таблицу с кучей столбцов, данные которых подтягиваются из разных таблиц. Я думаю все это закэшировать в одну таблицу и обновлять по крону раз в сутки. Вопрос в том нужны ли PK (primary key)? Я точно знаю что ни из каких таблиц на нее ссылок не будет (зачем?). Не будет ли это влиять на производительность?

И еще один вопрос: как быть с индексами? Я никогда раньше их не использовал и пока плохо понимаю их (хотя вики читал уже). Столбцов много, поиск/сортировка будет возможен по каждому из них и почти все они текстовые (кроме дат, которые числом вида TIMESTAMP хранятся чтобы можно было по ним сортировать тоже). Мне что повесить по индексу на каждый столбец? Или один но составной на все?

Comment: Если в условии отбора не будет столбцов с которых начинается индекс он не сможет быть использован. так что если условия отдельные, то и индексы придется делать отдельные. но при этом это будет занимать много места и операции вставки записей будут дольше, чем если бы индексов не было. Если не предполагается удалять или модифицировать конкретные записи (что надо делать по уникальному полю, типа первичного ключа), то ключ действительно не нужен

Comment: А может, вам отдельная таблица и не нужна, а достаточно создать соответствующее представление (VIEW)?

Comment: @Mike, изменять/удалять ничего не буду, скорее всего буду при общем обновлении делать просто truncate таблицы и заново ее заполнять, а выборка будет всего сразу, только блоками по N-записей чтобы не убить сервер запросом на несколько тысяч записей (через offset/limit, для этого же вроде PK не нужен?). 

А что с индексами я не понял все-таки? На вставку мне пофиг - она будет при обновлении раз в сутки незаметно для пользователя. Главное чтобы выборка быстро работала (в т.ч. поиск и сортировка).

Comment: @Yaant КЭП ты ли это? А о чем по вашему я говорю? Вывод на страницу. Конечно у меня есть вьюха - глупый вопрос. Но записей много тысяч и их нельзя просто так вывести скопом (я пробовал, ждать загрузку страницы пришлось больше минуты). Поэтому кэширование тут обязательно в том или ином виде.

Comment: Тогда вам необходим первичный ключ или другое поле в котором записи будут строго пронумерованы (без пропусков) в порядке требуемой сортировки. Что бы запросы `offset limit` преобразовать в `where ID between Start and End`. Потому что offset сначала читает записи с диска, а потом их просто выкидывает. Т.е. он основная причина любых тормозов при выборке страницами

Comment: @Mike Вы что не в курсе синтаксиса SQL? ... `select * from mytable limit 10, 10` (где 10, 10 - offset, limit). Как вы живете то так?

Comment: А что касается индексов, если у вас запросы идут иногда по одним полям, иногда по другим - то нужны отдельные индексы на отдельные колонки. Композитный индекс из 3х колонок может быть использвано только при запросах вида `where column1=X and column2=Y and column3 > Z` причем для такого запроса column3 должна быть в индексе последней

Comment: @Mike Если я сделаю по индексу на каждый столбец - это ускорит выборку по произвольным столбцам?

Comment: @DarkByte Я в курсе такого синтаксиса, но кроме самого синтаксиса я в курсе того, как БД у себя внутри обрабатывает такой запрос, так вот, она сначала читает с диска 20 записей, потом первые 10 из них просто выкидывает (не использует), а оставшиеся отдает клиенту. Т.е. разница в нагрузке от такого запроса и от запроса без limit только в том, что записи не идут по сети от сервера к клиенту. Но нагрузка на диск остается (а диск обычно главное узкое место в любой БД)

Comment: @Mike Первый раз такое слышу. И первый раз вижу такой странный подход. Так или иначе я использую готовый виджет который через ActiveQuery сам управляет запросом и он реализует пагинацию именно на limit/offset. P.S. А разве для выборки по тому же PK базе не потребуется точно также перебирать все записи пока она не найдет нужные?

Comment: А вот индексы как раз для этого и  нужны, (а PK создается за счет уникального индекса), при запросе по диапазону он быстро, за несколько шагов по двоичному дереву индекса найдет указатель на первую запись из диапазона и далее найдет остальные двигаясь по указателям в той же ветви индекса. В случае limit он так же может отсчитать записи по индексу (но ничего не ища, а перебирая все дерево), в случае если перед limit указан order by по тому полю, по которому есть индекс (но в любом случае это медленнее) а если order by по нужному полю нет, то только полным перебором таблицы

Comment: И к сожалению большинство разработчиков, делающих пагинацию не задумываются о таких особенностях БД. Да и без limit невозможно сделать универсального решения. Любое решение пагинации, которое должно работать быстро должно делаться для конкретного случая, исходя из конкретной ситуации (вот например https://ruhighload.com/post/Paging+using+MySQL). Раз вы решили делать кеш, то это очень хороший повод внедрить вместе с ним и такое решение, потому что это та редкая ситуация, когда вы можете себе позволить пронумеровать записи в нужном порядке и не беспокоится о пропуске номеров при удалениях.

Comment: @Mike Как я уже сказал виджет сам реализует пагинацию. Я не могу на него повлиять (и [это](http://demos.krajee.com/dynagrid-demo) лучший виджет который я нашел). К тому же как я уже сказал - я не буду удалять отдельные записи. Никогда. Просто иногда буду делать TRUNCATE чтобы очистить весь кэш разом.

Comment: И да, если вы сделаете индексы по отдельным столбцам то это ускорит запросы, выполняемые по этим столбцам (но одновременно может использоваться только один индекс, оптимизатор постарается взять лучший в конкретном случае). Только избегайте создания индекса по столбцам, в которых слишком мало _разных_ значений (например пол человека или какое нибудь поле со значениями yes/no) , если оптимизатор додумается его использовать (что в принципе вряд ли) то это сильно замедлит запрос

Comment: @Mike Хмм, у меня есть столбцы - справочники. Типа разные варианты статуса, там их правда не два, но штук 10-20 (разных значений).

Comment: Скажем так, если запрос по конкретному значению ключа получает более 10% всех записей таблицы, то по индексу он будет работать медленнее, чем полным сканированием таблицы. Если какой то конкретный статус редкий (Например "В работе") то по нему поиск по индексу будет быстрым, но если это статус у большинства записей (например "архив"), то по нему поиск по индексу противопоказан